# Citing the 10 heuristics of Jakob Nielsen

Tags: usability, heuristics

I am writing a research proposal, I expect those who read it might have very little knowledge about usability.

I wanted to cite the 10 heuristics of Jakob Nielsen. Is there a paper/book that talks about them that I can refer to? I'd rather not refer to a website in the proposal, since even though I know useit.com is a trusted source, I am not sure whether the reviewing committee will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I remember correctly Nielsen's current heuristics are the ones or based on the ones in:

> Nielsen, J. (1994b). Enhancing the explanatory power of usability
>   heuristics. Proc. ACM CHI'94 Conf. (Boston, MA, April 24-28), 152-158.

I believe the original heuristics were published in

> Nielsen, J., & Molich, R. (1990). Heuristic evaluation of user
>   interfaces, Proc. ACM CHI'90 Conf. (Seattle, WA, 1-5 April), 249-256.
>
> or
>
> Molich, R., & Nielsen, J. (1990). Improving a human-computer dialogue,
>   Communications of the ACM 33, 3 (March), 338-348.

Comment: They weren't stated in "Improving a human-computer dialogue", which I found on Google Scholar. But I couldn't find the other paper, so I believe the original heuristics were published in Nielsen, J., & Molich, R. (1990). Heuristic evaluation of user interfaces, Proc. ACM CHI'90 Conf. (Seattle, WA, 1-5 April), 249-256.

Answer (score 3):

The ones mentioned should have them.

But according to [this article in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_evaluation), you should find them also in the book Usability Engineering.